# How can I use values for the plot point symbols for a scatter plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, symbols

I've used ggplot2 in the past, but I'm stumped on this one. I'd like to create a scatter plot and use the values in a column as point symbols rather than the standard ggplot symbols. Has anyone done this before?

Thanks.

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

```
a <- data.frame(X = runif(n = 10),
                Y = runif(n = 10), 
                VAL = 1:10)

library(ggplot2)


ggplot(a, aes(x = X, y = Y))+geom_text(aes(label = VAL))
```